# Long form of an arithmetic sequence formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been studying arithmetic sequences and am finding that I can do the formulas, but can't truly understand until I can do a long-form version of the formula.

Let's take the below:

$a$5 = 2+2(5-1)

I can do 2+2+2+2+2 to get to 10 or following the sequence step by step I can do 2,4,6,8,10. But how would I calculate these answers on something like a basic calculator?

**Edit**: In case unclear, I'm asking for the non-formulaic version to calculate what, given the above, would write as $a$n = $a$1 + d (n - 1).

**Edit 2**: Okay, say I give you any arithmetic sequence formula such as shown above, and I hand you a calculator as basic as the one shown in this image. How do you solve it? You don't just do $a$1 + $a$2 + $a$3 ... ad infinitum. How do you solve for it? All the more advanced calculators and services online provide none of the step-by-step process, so you get the final answer without understanding a thing, and there has to be a more effective way than just adding or subtracting to the nth term.

[image: Basic image of calculator]

Comment: In its current state, it's not too clear what this question is asking. Can you clarify further?

Comment: @Panphobia I have no idea what you just asked.

Comment: @par Can you elaborate on what's not clear? I'm not sure how I might break it down further.

Comment: Ok well you basically said that $a_5$ is equal to that expression. But no where did you define $a_n$. It isn't clear what you want.

Comment: @Panphobia Would it look something like this? $a$n = $a$1 + d (n - 1)

Comment: Yes, $a_1$ is the first element in the sequence, and $d$ is the difference between successive terms.

Comment: @Panphobia Okay, great. Hopefully that helps explain what I'm asking then.

Comment: Are you looking for $a_n=a_{n-1}+d$ then?

Comment: @par Sorry, no. I've added an edit which hopefully helps clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the formula $$a_n = a_1 + d(n-1)$$ is the explicit formula, or closed form. You don't need to calculate $a_4$ to calculate $a_5$. For example if we have the same formula as you have in your post, $a_n = 2+ 2(n-1)$ then if you want to calculate $a_{10}$ you just plug in 10 to the equation and compute it using a calculator if you like $$a_{10}= 2 + 2(10-1)$$

Comment: Perhaps my edit was missed while you wrote, but I want to know how to calculate these without the formula just being entered into the calculator.

Comment: Well if you have a sequence lets say $$1,4,7,10,13,...$$, then we know $d=3$ since the difference between successive terms is $3$ and we know $a_1=1$ since the first term is $1$. So you get $a_n = 1+3(n-1)$. Is that what you were looking for? Do you not understand the actual formula?

Comment: Yes but knowing $a$1 and the difference doesn't get me closer when the only method I know on paper or with a basic calculator is 1+3+3+3+3...

Comment: It's actually the same, the example you gave if you have $1+3+3+3+3$ you can factor out a $3$ and you get $1+3(1+1+1+1)=1+3(4)=1+3(5-1)=a_{5}$. I don't think I know what you actually want, do you want to understand how the formula works? Because the formula works in the same way that your method on paper works.

Comment: There we are! That's what I was looking for. Whatever format you just demonstrated and I was calling "long form." $a$100 = 9 + 7 (100 - 1) can be written in a basic calculator as 9 + 7 * 99. The formula simply doesn't help without understanding the basic math as it abstracts away the foundational stuff I'm missing. Now you've helped clarify that area for me.